# BLKFlexibleHeightBar behavior definer does not conform to UITableViewDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

So I'm using [this library](https://github.com/bryankeller/BLKFlexibleHeightBar) that allows me to make a bar on top of a tableview that compresses when I scroll down. Now I installed it in my Swift project using a bridging header. So I followed the implementation guide, converting all the code to Swift code. It all worked fine until I reached a problem in the "Configuring Bar Behavior" section.

*Bar behavior definer* is the part that knows when to scale up/down the bar depending on how far through you've scrolled in your table. So it uses the `UITableViewDelegate` (TVD) to do so. But looking at the [source code](https://github.com/bryankeller/BLKFlexibleHeightBar/blob/master/BLKFlexibleHeightBar/BLKFlexibleHeightBarBehaviorDefiner.h) for the BarBehaviorDefiner, you can see that it implements the `UIScrollViewDelegate` only.

This is the problem. I need to set the tableview's delegate to one of the objects of type BLKFlexibleHeightBarBehaviorDefiner, but they are not of type `UITableViewDelegate`.

```
self.tableView.delegate = (id<UITableViewDelegate>)myBar.behaviorDefiner;
```

Now I know that TVD [implements SVD](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/) as part of it, but I can't set a SVD to something requiring a TVD.

**Here's what I've tried:**

1. Linking my table as a UIScrollView instead of a UITableView. Code:

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var table: UIScrollView!

   /*
   * irrelevant code *
   */

   headerBar.behaviorDefiner = SquareCashStyleBehaviorDefiner()
   table.delegate = headerBar.behaviorDefiner
   ```

This results in the bar actually compressing, but the table does not move with the bar. It just stays where it is, leaving a white space where the bar is compressed.

2. Optionally casting like in the implementation guide. Code:

   @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

   ```
   /*
   * irrelevant code *
   */

   headerBar.behaviorDefiner = SquareCashStyleBehaviorDefiner()
   table.delegate = headerBar.behaviorDefiner as? UITableViewDelegate
   ```

This doesn't cast it. The app does nothing when I scroll down the table.

3. Forced casting to a `UITableViewDelegate`. Code:

   @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

   ```
   /*
   * irrelevant code *
   */

   headerBar.behaviorDefiner = SquareCashStyleBehaviorDefiner()
   table.delegate = headerBar.behaviorDefiner as! UITableViewDelegate
   ```

This returns error `could not cast value of type 'UIScrollViewDelegate' to 'UITableViewDelegate'`.

I think it may be because I'm doing this in swift, but this error shouldn't be based on language?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this problem.

You´ll need to edit the BLKDelegateSplitter.h @interface declaration. Replace it with:

```
@interface BLKDelegateSplitter : NSObject <NSObject, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Source: https://github.com/bryankeller/BLKFlexibleHeightBar/issues/42

Answer (score 0):

add this extension for solve this issue as per new repo. update 
this is work for me .
if you are use collection view than change delegate

```
extension BLKFlexibleHeightBarBehaviorDefiner :UITableViewDelegate{

}
```